# How to calculate multiplicative inverse using reverse extended GCD algorithm

Tags: cryptography

I followed [How to calculate the inverse key matrix in Hill Cipher algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960190/how-to-calculate-the-inverse-key-matrix-in-hill-cipher-algorithm) for the answer but couldn't get how to calculate 'x' in the problem given in the post using extended GCD algorithm

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422223/encryption-rsa-algorithm/6449214#6449214)
(the question there is about RSA, but what you are looking for is the extended euclidean algorithm - EEA)